# What techniques are used to change the color of a particle board's veneer & edge banding?

Tags: particle-board

I found a piece of particle board that seems to be strong enough to hold an Apple 17 inch monitor, since it has the size and thickness requirements.

I'm toying with the idea of changing the color of this wood, but since it's particle board, with a veneer and edge banding (all of these are terms I learned today) I don't know how hard this is to do.

- What are the general steps I need to follow to change this wood to another color, assuming I live in NYC and have no tools but can buy them?
- Is there any advice you would like to give for getting the table legs and attaching them to the board?
- Is it more economical to start from scratch and just buy a ready made particle board of this size with the right color?   Home Depot has nothing that will help me here.

Monitor stand that will hold [one or two 27 inch monitors](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MC914LL/B/apple-thunderbolt-display-27-inch?fnode=53)  on a [Sanus monitor stand](http://store.apple.com/us/product/H6017LL/A/sanus-swivel-column-clamp-mount-vmd2-b1)

[image: top view]

Penny included for relative thickness.

[image: bottom view]

Comment: paint it or buy something in the colour you want.

Answer (score 1):

The cheapest, easiest no tools (except scissors) method is to use contact paper. It is available at most hardware or decorating centers.  It is preglued vinyl sheet on a roll similar to wallpaper. Several wood grains are usually available. It used to be used commonly as cabinet shelf lining. With practice you can get decent results, it is water resistant and cleanable.